# Dollar prefixed field not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb, go

I got this error:

```
panic: multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{The dollar ($) prefixed field '$set' in 'conversations.newest_message.$set' is not valid for storage.}]}, {<nil>}]
```

Here is the data I want to update, and I want to update newest_message inside conversations:

```
{
    "_id" : "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1",
    "conversations" : [ 
        {
            "conversation_id" : "VOoHg7nY4xBcrQtzxokbM9aStSSqei44",
            "newest_message" : {
                "user_name" : "",
                "data" : {
                    "description" : "",  
                },
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the mongoldb query:

```
db.collectionA.update(
    {
        _id: "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1", 
        "conversations.conversation_id": "VOoHg7nY4xBcrQtzxokbM9aStSSqei44"
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "conversations.$.newest_message": {new_update_data_here}
    }
)
```

and here is the Golang code, I'm using mongodb driver not mgo:

```
filter = bson.M{
                    "_id":                           id,
                    "conversations.conversation_id": messageReceived.ConversationID,
                }
update = bson.M{
                    "$set": bson.M{
                        "conversations": bson.M{
                            "newest_message": newestMessage,
                        },
                    },
                }

_, err = d.DB.Collection(collectionUserInformation).UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
```

Comment: Which mongo version you have?

Comment: what is the value of `newestMessage`  in your last code block, are you sure you have not set it  `bson.M{"$set": .....}` somewhere

Comment: @tarrsalah my version is: MongoDB shell version v4.2.1

Comment: @topenion my newest_message variable looks like this, it's same as new_update_data_here in mongodb query command above: 
{
    "user_name" : "David",
    "data" : {
            "description" : "this is the message",  
      },
}
And I'm pretty sure that var update is the first place I use operator $set

Comment: I cannot get the same error but it complains until I wrap `newest_message` with a `bson.M`: `"newest_message": bson.M{"user_name": "newU", "data": "newData"},`. But it's hard to be 100% sure if that's also your problem since we cannot see what `newest_message` is. Can you add an example that can be fully reproduced (with `newest_message` being built there or directly with a string)? And give it a try to add bson.M{..} to `newest_message`

Comment: @SPM below is the full mongodb query command and the result I want:

> db.A.find( {_id: "ArQB"} )
{"_id" : "ArQB", "cons" : [{"con_id" : "nvxw", "newest_msg" : {"u_name" : "", "seen" : false}}]}

> db.A.updateOne({_id: "ArQB", "cons.con_id": "nvxw"}, {"$set": {"cons.$.newest_msg": {"u_name": "David", "content": "can you see this?", "seen": true}}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }

> db.A.find( {_id: "ArQB"})
{"_id" : "ArQB", "cons" : [{"con_id" : "nvxw", "newest_msg" : {"u_name" : "David", "content" : "can you see this?", "seen" : true}}]}

Comment: @HoangVo But how do you build `newest_message` ? If I re-use your examples passing a `bson.M` as `newest_message` the update works fine: `update := bson.M{
  "$set": bson.M{
   "cons": bson.M{
    "newest_message": bson.M{"u_name": "David", "content": "can you see this?", "seen": true},
   },
  },
 }`

Comment: @SPM here is the link I show you the whole mongodb query and Golang code: https://codeshare.io/5PMjWd

Comment: @HoangVo Thanks for the code snippet (though it contains 2 syntax errors, so I don't think it compiles/runs: comma after `false` at line 156; and a missing `bson.M` before the `{` at line 150). I still couldn't get the error you mentioned but I understood the kind of update you want to perform thanks to the shell example. I will post an answer with the code to perform that same update without overriding the content of the document  as happens now.

Answer (score 0):

Using as initial document the one from the [example](https://codeshare.io/5PMjWd):

```
{
        "_id" : "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1",
        "settings" : {
                "general" : {
                        "languages" : [
                                {
                                        "label" : "English",
                                        "value" : "eng"
                                }
                        ],
                        "contact" : "No one",
                        "language" : [
                                {
                                        "label" : "English",
                                        "value" : "eng"
                                },
                                {
                                        "label" : "English",
                                        "value" : "eng"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "block_list" : [
                        "qGXVFjeZeFwrZjURfcZHqkCbgO91Gbu87KXx3Ba5",
                        "hFkF7DjPwBB6G2qbNT0J1ZROd3rxNLrZ5zt-HmMK"
                ],
                "auto_reply" : {
                        "set_auto_reply" : false,
                        "auto_reply_messages" : [ ]
                }
        },
        "conversations" : [
                {
                        "conversation_id" : "VOoHg7nY4xBcrQtzxokbM9aStSSqei44",
                        "people" : [
                                {
                                        "user_id" : "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1",
                                        "user_name" : "Dat Vo"
                                },
                                {
                                        "user_id" : "qGXVFjeZeFwrZjURfcZHqkCbgO91Gbu87KXx3Ba5",
                                        "user_name" : "An Son"
                                }
                        ],
                        "newest_message" : {
                                "user_name" : "",
                                "data" : {
                                        "description" : "",
                                        "host" : "",
                                        "image" : "",
                                        "title" : "",
                                        "type" : "",
                                        "url" : "",
                                        "youtube_video_id" : ""
                                },
                                "seen" : false
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

you can replace `newest_message` element inside the `conversations` array using `$set` and the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

> update := bson.M{ "$set": bson.M{
>           "conversations.$.newest_message": bson.M{...

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
defer cancel()

filter := bson.M{
    "_id":                           "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1",
    "conversations.conversation_id": "VOoHg7nY4xBcrQtzxokbM9aStSSqei44",
}
update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "conversations.$.newest_message": bson.M{
            "message_id": "saisa",
            "user_id":    "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1",
            "user_name":  "Dat Vo",
            "content":    "this is the new msg",
            "created_at": "12345678",
            "seen":       false,
        },
    },
}

_, err2 := d.DB.Collection(collectionUserInformation).UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
if err2 != nil {
    panic(err2)
}
```

It will return the following updated document:

```
{
        "_id" : "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1",
        "settings" : {
                "general" : {
                        "languages" : [
                                {
                                        "label" : "English",
                                        "value" : "eng"
                                }
                        ],
                        "contact" : "No one",
                        "language" : [
                                {
                                        "label" : "English",
                                        "value" : "eng"
                                },
                                {
                                        "label" : "English",
                                        "value" : "eng"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "block_list" : [
                        "qGXVFjeZeFwrZjURfcZHqkCbgO91Gbu87KXx3Ba5",
                        "hFkF7DjPwBB6G2qbNT0J1ZROd3rxNLrZ5zt-HmMK"
                ],
                "auto_reply" : {
                        "set_auto_reply" : false,
                        "auto_reply_messages" : [ ]
                }
        },
        "conversations" : [
                {
                        "conversation_id" : "VOoHg7nY4xBcrQtzxokbM9aStSSqei44",
                        "people" : [
                                {
                                        "user_id" : "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1",
                                        "user_name" : "Dat Vo"
                                },
                                {
                                        "user_id" : "qGXVFjeZeFwrZjURfcZHqkCbgO91Gbu87KXx3Ba5",
                                        "user_name" : "An Son"
                                }
                        ],
                        "newest_message" : {
                                "created_at" : "12345678",
                                "seen" : false,
                                "message_id" : "saisa",
                                "user_id" : "iNIXU8dgLgg-KdC3FE1hX8qBpY44hTF-2m-h-RG1",
                                "user_name" : "Dat Vo",
                                "content" : "this is the new msg"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Your previous attempt was replacing the `conversations` array for a document with one doc `conversations` that contained just `newest_message`. You want to use the `$set` operator with the positional `$` operator providing the full path so it just replaces the sub-document you want.

Comment: Thanks for your support, finally I found the reason why. Because the variable I use to store newest_message is modified in another goroutine (I use goroutines to concurrently connect to multiple collections) and I totally forgot about it so I thought it's value remains the same as I show you. Thank you again for spending time fix this problem.